Mempool TX always zero
I cant figure out this one. Its always show me 0 TX in my mempool. Well i saw some TX yesterday, but then i have installed ogmios and now I dont see any TX in my mempool. Where to look?
cardano-cli query tx-mempool info --mainnet --socket-path $HOME/src/network-config/mainnet/socket/node.socket
{
"capacityInBytes": 178176,
"numberOfTxs": 0,
"sizeInBytes": 0,
"slot": 129626989
}
I have like 25 conenctions with peers. when i check with ss -an | grep 3001
I also have enabled "TraceMempool": true, in config file.
Node is synced.
card@ns310818:~$ cardano-cli query tip --mainnet

{
"block": 10583231,
"epoch": 497,
"era": "Babbage",
"hash": "3dcd064958e2caf2c569e8a2e7002c7818b8993d6804c5c4aec9b32d31af3fe8",
"slot": 129627583,
"slotInEpoch": 286783,
"slotsToEpochEnd": 145217,
"syncProgress": "100.00"
}
I even upgraded it to 9.0.0 just now, but still no any TX in mempool. I'm totally lost.
Cant find any info online also.
Hope there are somebody with some tips.
Thanks
PS.
I use this configuration in my topology.json https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/mainnet/topology.json
I have just full node.

Please do not just paste screenshots. They are a pain in the neck for people with high DPI screens. Please copy and paste text instead.

Is your node a relay? Which topology is it using? Is it synced with the rest of the network?

Got it, removed screenshot. And added some more info.

Most likely don't have In connections to your node from other nodes which have transaction in their mempool.

Hi, thanks for answer. But I told i have 25 connections but just now counted and its 50 Established connections with other nodes. Dont that mean I have In connections as this is p2p if im not wrong. I'm using this command to check that: ss -an | grep 3001

Seems you are right, when i run this: curl -s  127.0.0.1:12798/metrics | grep "cardano_node_metrics_connectionManager_incomingConns"
I see 0. So that's probably it, and as i read around, there is not any fix for that also. Some guys suggested trying topology updating stript even with P2P. but hats also works so so. Basically, there is no obvious answer as i understand. I'm opened to suggestions.

Topology updater works very fine.
